# ArangoDB edge collections in multiple graphs

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb

Why does ArangoDB only allow a single edge collection definition globally? My teammate noted today that, when creating a graph, we're prompted to add an edge collection and the appropriate `_to` and `_from` collections; but when we create a second graph, the `_to` and `_from` are required to be identical to the first graph's `_to` and `_from` collections for this edge collection. There is a use case in which I would want one graph to load a subset of another graph, or utilize the same edge collection to show relationships that are different in each graph I define.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222648/multiple-graphs-using-same-edge-definitions-in-arangodb) alluded to some design criteria I suspect are part of the reason, but I'm wondering why it's not possible to create a graph with a different set of vertex collections using the same edge collection.

Comment: The decision to make it globally, was to allow better performance and clustering. I'm not certain I correctly understood your use-case. So before answering let me try to understand it better: You could define a graph with E1 = {V0,V1} -> V2. In this case you could not use a 2nd graph restricting to V0. Or you can split it into 2 defs E1a = V0 -> V2 and E1b = V1 -> V2 for the 1st graph. In this case you could define a 2nd graph using only E1a. You would need 2 edge collection in this case. Is that what you have in mind with your use case?

Comment: In this case, querying these two edge collections as if they were a single document collection would be a little more difficult, but what you described would be a reasonable workaround for what I have in mind. It is a bit more complicated than I'd hope for, but presumably it simplifies ArangoDB in other areas.